# Tycho plugin cannot build product

Tags: maven, e4, tycho

I have an E4 project that contains a product and a plugin. When building the plugin based application using Tycho I get the following error.

```
Cannot resolve dependencies of product CR-IT_client.product:
eclipse-plugin artifact with ID "CR-IT_client" and version matching "0.0.0" was not found in the target platform
```

Last week I compiled it without any errors but after clearing the maven cache it doesn't work anymore. How can I fix this?

When using the cache again it will compile but it will use the old jar file instead of the last compiled one.

When compiling with 'mvn clean install' I get the following Maven output:

```
INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\air27654\Documents\Source\framework\CR-IT client\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- target-platform-configuration:1.0.0:target-platform (default-target-platform) @ eclipse-repository ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tycho-p2-publisher-plugin:1.0.0:publish-products (default-publish-products) @ eclipse-repository ---
[ERROR] Cannot resolve dependencies of product CR-IT_client.product:
[ERROR]   eclipse-plugin artifact with ID "CR-IT_client" and version matching "0.0.0" was not found in the target platform
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] RCP Parent ......................................... SUCCESS [  5.794 s]
[INFO] CR IT Client Repository ............................ FAILURE [  5.034 s]
[INFO] CR IT Client Target Definition ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 05:26 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-10T07:48:10+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 161M/692M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-publisher-plugin:1.0.0:publish-products (default-publish-products) on project eclipse-repository: Execution default-publish-products of goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-publisher-plugin:1.0.0:publish-products failed: Cannot resolve dependencies of product CR-IT_client.product. See log for details. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :eclipse-repository
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tycho requires you to have two projects, one for the [`eclipse-repository`](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/eclipse-repository) and one for the [`eclipse-plugin`](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Packaging_Types#eclipse-plugin) that defines your product. Both should be `<modules>` of your aggregator POM. Then Tycho will be able to find everything (even with a clean cache) on a single `mvn clean install`.

Comment: When using the cache it will compile the product. But it will use the old plugin instead of the new one. I will add the mvn clean install output

Comment: Thank you. That helps. The problem is that when you’ve cleared the cache (`~/.m2/repository`) a `mvn clean install` has nowhere to obtain the `CR-IT_client` bundle from. With a clean cache, the build can only *see* `RCP Parent`, `CR IT Client Repository`, and `CR IT Client Target Definition` + all plugins defined in the target definition. Apparently, `CR-IT_client` is **not** in the target definition and **not** in the reactor. Why not at `CR-IT_client` as a `<module>`, so that it will be built by the same `mvn clean install` that builds the product?

Comment: I have a plugin based RCP application. So the product file will contain a reference to the plugin. The main project (with the product and plugin file is included in the 'CR IT Client Repository' project?

Comment: Not sure I understand. How do you built the `CR-IT_client`? Do you mean that the `CR IT Client Repository` contains both a `plugin.xml` and a `category.xml`? If so, that’s not supported by Tycho; you need separate projects: One with packaging `eclipse-plugin` and one with packaging `eclipse-repository`. Have a look at [this example](http://git.eclipse.org/c/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho-demo.git/tree/itp04-rcp).

Comment: The repository contains the product file and the plugin.xml

Comment: AFAIK, the plugin that defines the product needs to be in a separate (Maven) project, which is also a `<module>` of your aggregator POM. Then Tycho should be able to find everything with a clean cache on a single `mvn clean install`.